# Scoping through association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Consider the following

```
class Engineer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ideas
  scope :masters, -> { where(educational_level: ["master", "candidate"]) }
end

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engineer
  scope :popular, -> { where("rating > ?", 4) }
end
```

Now, let's say I want to retrieve all popular ideas conceived by master engineers ordered by the engineers' `age`. For simplicity, assume that `age` is just an integer column in the `engineers` table.

One way to do this is to first fetch the engineers.

```
popular_ideas_by_educated_engineers = []
Engineer.masters.order("age").each do |engineer|
  popular_ideas_by_educated_engineers += engineer.ideas.popular
end
```

This code has an n+1 issue, because ideas are not eager loaded and it overall feels clunky.

I would like to write the code in a way that allows to get the desired results by writing something like

```
Idea.popular.by_masters.order_by_engineer_age
```

Is this possible - and if so, how?

I know I can hardcode SQL into the `Idea` class which joins on `engineers` and imposes some limitations, but what I am looking for is utilizing the scopes already defined on the `Engineer` class.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and flip this around, like you suggest:

```
Idea.popular.includes(:engineer).by_masters.order('engineers.age')
```

Where your `by_masters` scope looks something like:

```
scope :by_masters, -> { where: { engineers: { educational_level: 'master' } } }
```

It's the `includes` call that forces a `JOIN` that makes this possible.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried something like that, but this litters the Idea class with knowledge about the Engineer class, for instance this code reveals the table name, two attributes called educational_level  and age and the constraints of the educational_level attribute. It would be great if this could be kept hidden, so Idea only uses the scopes and duplication thereby is avoided.

Comment: While you've got the right idea with keeping things hidden, Rails, and ActiveRecord in particular, is going to fight you every step of the way. Maybe you can find a way to do this without the conflicting concerns, but I think the best approach is to just go with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins and merges here:

```
class Engineer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :masters, -> { where(educational_level: ["master", "candidate"]) }
  scope :ordered_by_age, -> { order(:age) } 
end

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engineer

  scope :popular, -> { where("rating > ?", 4) }
  scope :by_master, -> { joins(:engineer).merge(Engineer.masters) }
  scope :order_by_engineer_age, -> { joins(:engineer).merge(Engineer.order_by_age) }
end
```